# determining an equality involving transcendence degrees of fields of fractions and residue fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $(A,p)$ be a local integral domain and $B=A[x]$, where $x$ is an indeterminate. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $B$ that contracts in $A$ to $p$, such that $\operatorname{ht}(P/pB)=1$.
Denote by $K_A,K_B$ the fields of fractions and $\kappa(p),\kappa(P)$ the residue fields.

Question: can we conclude that $\operatorname{tr.deg}_{\kappa(p)} \kappa(P)= \operatorname{tr.deg}_{K_A} K_B -1$? If yes, how can we see that?

Motivation: Matsumura's Theorem 15.5 (Commutative Ring Theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken $\operatorname{tr.deg}_{K_A} K_B =1$. Moreover, $P/pB$ is a prime ideal of $B/pB=(A/p)[x]$, so $P/pB$ is principal generated by an irreducible (monic) polynomial $f\in (A/p)[x]$. This shows that the ring extension $A/p\subset A[x]/P$ is integral, and therefore their fields of fractions give rise to an algebraic extension. (Convincing?)

Comment: It took me 40 minutes to understand what you are doing, but i think i got it: essentially $A[x]/P$ is a field isomorphic to $(A/p[x]) / (f)$ and because $f$ is irreducible over $A/p$ the field extension $A/p \subset (A/p[x])/(f)$ is algebraic. Correct?